# セッション変数内の配列にPOSTで送られたデータが既に存在する場合に配列の特定の要素の値を変更する方法

Tags: php

失礼します。
PHPでセッションを利用したショッピングカートのシステムを作っているのです。

現在、カート内に商品の重複をさせない処理まではできているのですが、カート内に同じIDの商品が存在する時には既にカート内に入っている商品の個数を追加する変更処理を行えるようにしたいです。

例）カート内　　：ID1　りんご　個数1
　　　　　↓
　　ユーザの行動：追加でりんごを2つカートに入れる
　　　　　↓
　　カート内　　：ID1　りんご　個数3

このような状態になるように処理をしたいです。
伝わっているでしょうか。

コードは以下の通りです。

```
//セッション変数「cart」が未設定の場合は空の配列に初期化
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}else if (is_string($_SESSION['cart'])){    
    //セッション変数「cart」に文字列が存在していれば配列セッションcartを代入 
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array($_SESSION['cart']); 
}

/********************追加処理**********************/    

$key = isset($_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]);

//セッション変数内にPOSTで送られてきたidと同じものが無かった場合の処理
if(!$key){
    if(isset($_POST['price'])){
        $price = $_POST['price'];

        if(isset($_POST['num'])){
            $num = $_POST['num'];
           $sum = $price * $num;
        }
    }
    //item_resultからpostでid,name,priceが送られてきたかを確認
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    if(isset($_POST['price'])){
    if(isset($_POST['num'])){
    if(isset($sum)){
    //送られてきたデータを配列に格納
    $item = array('id' => $_POST['id'],
                    'name' => $_POST['name'],
                    'price' => $_POST['price'],
                    'num' => $_POST['num'],
                    'sum' => $sum);
    }}}}
    }else{
        $msg = 'no item';   //何もカートに入れてませんよー
    }
}

//セッション変数「cart」に配列の中身を追加
if(isset($item)){
    $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']] = $item;
}

//表示するためにセッションの中身を配列に入れなおす
$print_cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
```

foreachで$print_cartを回しながら、POSTで送られたIDと配列内のIDが一致した場合にarray_spliceで置換したらどうかと考えたのですが書き方が分からず断念してしまいました。

やりたい事は、カート内に同じIDの処理が存在する時には既にカート内に入っている商品の個数を追加する変更処理です。

どうしたらよいのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: $keyにはtrueが入っていると思うのですが、$key['num']などはどういった意味になるのでしょうか？
ちなみにご指摘頂いたコードを入れてみたところ空白の要素にintで1と0が入った状態でエラーが出ました。

Comment: 本題とは関係ないですが気になったので。フォームから送信された価格`$_POST['price']`をそのまま使って合計を検索していますが、使う前に意図しない数値が送信されていないかのチェック、後処理で正規の価格を入れ直す、など適切な処理はされていますか。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
その処理はしていないです。
追加しないといけない処理ではあるので、後々追加していきたいと思います。

Comment: 指摘したような処理は「後から追加」するようなものではありません。他の質問も拝見しましたが、率直に言うとWebアプリケーションの作成に必要な最低限の知識に到達されていないように見受けられます。現状では致命的な脆弱性を抱えたアプリケーションになることが容易に想像できますので、実際のものを作る前に一通りのことをきちんとした書籍で勉強されることをおすすめします。PHPでのプログラミングと、Webアプリケーションに求められる様々な知識両方です。後者については「体系的に学ぶ安全なWebアプリケーションの作り方」という本がおすすめです。前者については申し訳ありませんが適切な本を紹介できませんのでご自分で探してください。

Comment: ご指摘、ありがとうございます。
しっかりと勉強された方から見れば酷いコードだとは思います。
学校で課題として作っているのですが、ecサイトを作るにあたっての必要なphpの知識をまだ授業として習っていない状態での制作なので試行錯誤しながらなんとか動くようにしていくのが精一杯なのが現状です。ご了承ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ちょっとロジックが複雑だったので整理しました。
これ単体でphpファイルとして動きます。

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $num = $_POST['num'];
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']])){
        $num += $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]['num'];
    }
    $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']] = array(
        'id' => $_POST['id'],
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'price' => $_POST['price'],
        'num' => $num,
        'sum' => $_POST['price'] * $num
    );
    $print_cart = $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']];
}else{
    $print_cart = array('id' => '', 'name' => '', 'price' => '', 'num' => 0, 'sum' => 0);
    $msg = 'no item';
}
?>
テスト用フォーム
<meta charset="utf-8">
<form method="post">
    ID <input name="id" value="<?php echo $print_cart['id'] ?>"><br>
    名前 <input name="name" value="<?php echo $print_cart['name'] ?>"><br>
    価格 <input name="price" value="<?php echo $print_cart['price'] ?>"><br>
    数量 <?php echo $print_cart['num'] ?><br>
    追加数量 <input name="num" value="0"><br>
    合計  <?php echo $print_cart['sum'] ?><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

追加数量を入れてポストするごとに個数が足されます。
参考になれば幸いです。
セキュリティの処理は入れていないので気をつけてください。